# Mongodb insertOne changing the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I was learning to insert data into mongodb, here is the code:

```
console.log(this.data) //first
userCollection.insertOne(this.data)
console.log(this.data) //second
```

The first log:

> {username: aaa, password: aaa}

The second log:

> {username: aaa, password: aaa, _id: some_id_here}

Where is **_id** from?

Does mongodb change data or does it is work like callback?

Like when we insert data in mongodb it sends the data that has been inserted back?

Comment: id comes form auto generate key mongodb. if you do not want to id than id set false when defined schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id` is the unique id created by mongoDB. SO that each and every document will have this.

Refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: So it's like the mongodb send back the data with _id?

Comment: @Septiana Yoga Ya exactly.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers are correct but they fail to explain why this happens in the first place.

If you check the Node.js MongoDB Driver API for the [insertOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#insertOne) method you will notice that there is a property you can pass into the option object called `forceServerObjectId`, what this does and I am quoting:

> Force server to assign _id values instead of driver.

and by default is set `false`.

So, if you are using the driver:

> If documents passed in do not contain the `_id` field, one will be added to each of the documents missing it by the driver, mutating the document.

This behavior can be overridden by setting the `forceServerObjectId` property to `true`.

Boom, there you go

Answer (score 0):

it's a ObjectId. 
Generate By default for every document.
So every document will have it.

Answer (score 0):

_id is a unique value generated for every inserted document in mongoDB. It is treated as a primary key.